# Bringing equation to canonical form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the canonical form of $x^2+2xy+3y^2-4x-5y+10=0$

I found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and got to

$$(2+\sqrt(2))x^2+(2-\sqrt(2))y^2-\frac{9+4\sqrt(2)}{\sqrt{4+2\sqrt(2)}}x-\frac{9+-5\sqrt(2)}{\sqrt{4-2\sqrt(2)}}y+10=0$$

How an I bring this experssion to $x'^2+y'^2+d=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}
   Q(x,y)
   &=x^2+2xy+3y^2-4x-5y+10 \\
   &= \begin{pmatrix} x & y\end{pmatrix}
      \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
      \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}
      +
      \begin{pmatrix} -4 & -5\end{pmatrix}
     \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}
      + 10
\end{align}
$

where the eigernvectors of 
$A_{33} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$
are $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -1-\sqrt 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$
and $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -1+\sqrt 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

with corresponding eigenvalues 
   $\lambda_1 = 2-\sqrt 2$
   and  $\lambda_2 = 2+\sqrt 2$

So $A_{33} = SJS^{-1}$ where

$S = \begin{pmatrix} -1-\sqrt 2 & -1+\sqrt 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$J = \begin{pmatrix} 2-\sqrt 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2+\sqrt 2 \end{pmatrix}$

$S^{-1} = \dfrac{-1}{2 \sqrt 2}
\begin{pmatrix} 
    1 & -1+\sqrt 2 \\ 
   -1 & -1-\sqrt 2
\end{pmatrix}$

The matrix of the quadratic equation, $Q$, is
$A_Q = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & -2 \\
    1 & 3 & -\frac 52\\
   -2 & -\frac 52 & 10
\end{pmatrix}$.

Since $\det A_Q = \dfrac{47}{4} \ne 0$ and $\det A_{33} = 2>0$, $Q(x,y)$ is the equation of an ellipse.

The center of the conic is at

$$\begin{pmatrix} x_c \\ y_c\end{pmatrix}
   =-\dfrac 12
     \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
     \begin{pmatrix} -4 \\ -5\end{pmatrix}
   =\frac 14\begin{pmatrix} 7 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

The equation of the centered conic is $Q_c(x,y)=0$ where

$$Q_c(x,y)=Q\left(x + \frac 74, y + \frac 14 \right) = x^2 + 2xy+3y^2 + \frac{47}{8}$$

The standard form of the centered conic is

\begin{align}
   \lambda_1 x^2 + \lambda_2 y^2 &= -\dfrac{\det AQ}{\det A_{33}}\\
   (2-\sqrt 2)x^2 + (2+\sqrt 2)y^2 &= -\dfrac{47}{8}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I have first translated to eliminate first degree terms
$$x=x'+ \frac74;\;y=y'+\frac 14$$
And I got
$$x'^2+2 x'\, y'+3 y'^2+\frac{47}{8}=0$$
Then I applied a rotation to gt rid of the $x'y'$ term
$$x'= X \cos (t)-Y \sin (t);\;y'=X \sin (t)+Y\cos (t)$$
The term $x'y'$ has a coefficient
$$-\sin ^2(t)+\cos ^2(t)+2 \sin (t) \cos (t)=0$$
which gives $t=\arctan \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)$

This means
$$\cos (t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^2+1}};\;\sin (t)=\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^2+1}}$$
plugging this in the equation in $x'$ and $y'$ gives
$$\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right) x^2+\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right) y^2+\frac{47}{8}=0$$
Which is a imaginary ellipse

Hope this helps